# error sql at level 1 insufficient privilage oracle

Tags: oracle, privileges, flashback

```
SQL> flashback table ticket to timestamp TO_TIMESTAMP('13-11-2018 22:30:56', 
                                                      'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
flashback table ticket to timestamp TO_TIMESTAMP('13-11-2018 22:30:56', 
            *                                    'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

> ***ERROR*** at line 1:
>
> ***ORA-00604 :*** error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
>
> ***ORA-01031 :*** insufficient privileges

*P.S. : I already added `flashback any table` system privilege.*

Comment: Do you have privileges for ticket and its foreign keys tables?

Comment: yeah i have crud privilage on ticket

Comment: Show table details (Foreign key, TABLES, SEQUENCES and INDEXES ...)

Comment: no foreign key only primary key i dont add sequences too i only make table ticket and add primary key in table ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Most probably you have a trigger such as `after event` type which contains some operations that prevent you perform your command line operations related with them. Try to disable those triggers, and then retry `flashback table ...`*

To detect the obstacle, use :

```
select owner, trigger_name
  from user_triggers -- for current schema, might be replaced with "dba_triggers" for the whole
 where trigger_type = 'AFTER EVENT';
```